# AutoKey repeating loop

Tags: python, autokey

I have been searching forums and the web for hours looking into a way of making a repeating python loop for Autokey. The goal is to allow timed intervals of key presses, such as pressing "1" every 16 seconds, "2" every 30, so on and so forth for as many keys as I may need (likely less than 8). I would also want to be able to end this process at the click of any combination. I have been testing looping only 1 keyboard input every 5 seconds, and I can easily make that work. I am fairly new to python and coding in general, and what has worked for me in the past does not here. I've tried:

```
import time
import sys
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        keyboard.send_key("4")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)
```

and variations there of, such as switching the while loop and try/except. It feels as though my keyboardinterrupt is not working properly, I've used ctrl -c and ctrl break, to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you're trying to type `4 8 15 16 23 42` every 108 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement, and from my searching, I found a [comment](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/504#issuecomment-763752809) from AutoKey developer.

These codes could be what you need:

```py
while True:
    retCode = keyboard.wait_for_keypress(
        'c', modifiers=['<ctrl>'], timeOut=5)
    if retCode:
        break
    keyboard.send_key("4")
```

Comment: You'd think that would work, but there's a deficiency in that API call and it does not return a retCode. The easiest way to break a loop like this is to use an AutoKey Global variable as illustrated [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Contributed-Scripts-2#toggle-a-looped-script).

Answer (score 0):

`KeyboardInterrupt` only catches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if it was send to the controlling terminal. This means that if you're pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from a different window, it will not catch.

To work around this, you need to register a keyboard shortcut on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and have it send a signal to your main script.

Comment: Is there a way of terminating a python script externally that could have a shortcut attached to it? currently I've been logging out and back in of my desktop user to kill the runaway script